# Is someone has a nice pointer or official solution to upgrade a dev phone 2 from 1.6 to 2.1

Tags: android

I'm developing an application targeting sdk 2.1 unfortunately my ADP2 is on 1.6
I'm looking for an official way to upgrade my dev phone 2 ADP2 from 1.6 to 2.1
I saw some pointers to cyanogenmod but it's chinese for me.

I don't know what is a mod and so on 
I suppose it's an image of the OS ? But how can I match version 2.1 with the version of the mod

thanks a lot

Comment: http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?/topic/394-cyanogenmod-5-for-dreammagic-mean-lean-pastry-machine-v507-05252010/
1. Root your device and install Clockwork Recovery (ROM Manager on the market) or Amon_RA's recovery (Dream / Magic)
>what does mean root ?
2. Do a Nandroid backup!
what is the command ?
3. Install the DangerSPL if you don't already have it
what is the command ?

4. WIPE (I cannot guarantee an upgrade from CM-4.2 to CM-5 will work)
what is the command ?
5. Install the ROM
adb flash... ?

Comment: what type of phone do you have? this belongs on android enthusiasts, not stackoverflow since it has nothing to do with code.